# Java regular expression matching for CSS child combinator with one character selectors

Tags: java, css, regex, xpath

I would like to replace the CSS child combinator ">" for the XPath child combinator "/".

Considering different existing CSS selectors, and after scaping some white spaces I try to match the regular expression:

```
([\w\-\*\.\#]|[\[[^\]]+\]])>([\w\-\*\.\#]|\[ )
```

and replace it with:

```
$1/$2
```

This works fine for all the cases I've found but one: when one of the selectors has only one character, and is caught between two child combinators, such as: "div>a>div".

Does anybody know how to handle the one letter character correctly?

I leave here some examples: http://fiddle.re/4xkrt

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you replace `>` by `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must repeat Alex's question.  "Why don't you just replace > with /"?

However if you insist to check that the > has content on both sides then lookarounds are the way to go.

```
(?<=[\w\-\*\.\#]|[\[[^\]]+\]])>(?=[\w\-\*\.\#]|\[ )
```

This just catches the > so replace with `/`.

Comment: I could use replace, but the whole CSS to XPath translator I use is implemented with an array of regular expressions and replacements using replaceAll(). The array is set in an order that matters. I wanted to find a way to keep this structure. It works with the expression you gave me, thanks!